# how defined target for drag and drop image

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

in my program i 4 imageview, imageview1 and imageview2 should drag and drop to imageview3 and imageview4

imageview1 should drop only in imageview3 and if droped another place should back to original place
and
imageview2 should drop only in imageview4 and if droped another place should back to original place

i write code and i dont know how defined the target of imageview1 and imageview2 and say if drope place exept this target back to original place

```
package com.test.dragplease;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DragpleaseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imageView4).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());


}



private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }




class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      //int action = event.getAction();
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          // do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //ClipData cd =  event.getClipData();
            //Item item = cd.getItemAt(0);
            //String resp = item.coerceToText(context).toString();


            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;

            //view being dragged and dropped
            ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

        //  dropped.setEnabled(false);

            //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being      dropped
            dropTarget.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getBackground());


            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());


        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

          return false;
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Check my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844743/draggable-button-getting-out-of-relativelayout-whenever-dragged). That's how it's done.

Comment: your code like my problem?i whant define the target and if user drop another place back to original place @Tushar

Comment: Yes, this is the way of doing it. I'm keeping imageview inside the relativelayout, you can change that to another view. Simply take X and Y of 3rd and 4th imageView and then on dragging 1st and 2nd Image, match their X and Y with 3rd image. If they match, perform operation accordingly. Same for 4th imageview.

Comment: @Tushar   can explain more fore me?

Answer (score 0):

in onTouchListener i should X and Y that image i drag like this

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        final int mX = (int) event.getX();
       final int mY = (int) event.getY();
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

and in action_drop i take X and Y that image i release that like this

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
         v.getX();
         v.getY();

        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //ClipData cd =  event.getClipData();
            //Item item = cd.getItemAt(0);
            //String resp = item.coerceToText(context).toString();


            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;

            //view being dragged and dropped
            ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

        //  dropped.setEnabled(false);

            //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
            dropTarget.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getBackground());


            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());


        break;
```

how i take X and Y other image?